# add Tip or Venue to foursquare by using a URL like /share.php url in Facebook

Tags: facebook-like, foursquare, facebook-social-plugins

Is there any way to add Venue/Tip to Foursquare without creating appID in developer.foursquare.com?

I need to confirm whether is there any provision for sharing content to foursquare by using a public url like Facebook share.php.

Comment: Hi, Any idea on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will need an app-id or authed user, due to the fact that every tip is from a user or linked to.

But they make exceptions when it comes to adding venues. 
At least you will need an app-id for that.

> **Adding Venues Without Authenticating Users First**
>
> This endpoint generally requires you to authenticate Foursquare users
>   before you can add venues on their behalf. In some cases, we’ll make
>   exceptions and allow applications to create new venues without
>   authenticating any users. If you’re interested in this feature, please
>   contact api@foursquare.com.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/add